# 'Future<QuerySnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<dynamic>'?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im struggling trying to use a streambuider. Im getting an error that says :

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<UserData>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<UserData, AsyncSnapshot<UserData>>#e2c02):
type 'Future<QuerySnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<dynamic>' of 'function result'
```

heres my code

```
 Stream myVideos;
getalldata() async {
    //get videos as future
    myVideos = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userid)
        .snapshots();

    var documents = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userid)
        .get();
    if (documents.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var item in documents.docs) {
        likes = item.data()['likes'].length + likes;
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        picturesdontexists = true;
      });
    }

    setState(() {
      dataisthere = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userforid>(context);
    return dataisthere == false
        ? Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()))
        : StreamBuilder<UserData>(
            stream: DatbaseService(uid: user?.uid).userData,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                UserData userData = snapshot.data;
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    elevation: 0.0,

-  - - - - - - - - -
    ),
                      ),
                   StreamBuilder(
                       stream: myVideos,
                        builder: ( context, snapshot) {
                       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                 return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                  }
                                   if(videos>0){
                                      print(snapshot.data);
                                   
                           return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                            crossAxisCount: 3,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              DocumentSnapshot video =
                                  snapshot.data.docs[index];

                              return InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context)
                                      .pushNamed(ChatFirstpage.route);
                                },
                                child: Card(
                                  elevation: 0.0,
```

What I think is that the error is thrown in the stream because before im using the stream myVideos im getting no error and all works fine .
Maye anyone can help Thank!. if you need more Information leave a comment .

Heres mine DatbaseService

```
class DatbaseService {
  static DatbaseService instance = DatbaseService();
  final String uid;
  String _messages = "messages";
  String _images = "images";

  DatbaseService({this.uid});


  //userData from snapshot
  UserData userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      email: snapshot.data()['email'],
      fullname: snapshot.data()['fullname'],
      password: snapshot.data()['password'],
      url: snapshot.data()['url'],
      username: snapshot.data()['username'],
    );
  }

//get user doc stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return myprofilsettings.doc(uid).snapshots().map(userDataFromSnapshot);
  }

``
```

Comment: show your stream DatbaseService

Comment: I update my code please check so you can see the DatbaseService.

Answer (score 1):

This usually arises when you are passing a Future where Stream should have gone or where you have defined the type of the variable as Stream but you are putting that variable equal to a future value.

I think instead of creating a variable like Stream myVideos you can directly put

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userid)
        .snapshots()
```

inside the stream builder.

Also please provide the whole code (DatbaseService).

Comment: I update my code please check so you can see the DatbaseService.